# How can i separate broadcasting routes authorization middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, broadcast

I need to authorize broadcasting routes through web middleware OR auth:api middleware. The code below authorizes the routes from api calls with `Authorization: Bearer 'token'` as request header with `socket.io-client` but it doesn't work with `csrfToken` , if i use just `Broadcast::routes()` it authorizes only the web subscribers

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(["middleware" => ["auth:api", "web"] ]);  
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

Is there any way to go through this, or maybe create two different groups of private channels and authorize them differently? I would appreciate your help with this!

Comment: hey elis. have you found the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best solution I have figured out. In your ***LoginController.php*** add *authenticated* function.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user){
      $bearer_token = $user->createToken('Web'); //This will create the bearer token when user successfully login
      Session::put('user_chat_token', $bearer_token->accessToken); //Store token in the session.
}
```

In your ***master.blade.php*** layout

```
<script>
     var access_token = '{{ (isset($access_token)) ? $access_token : "" }}';
</script>
```

Now get your access_token in the ***bootstrap.js***

```
 window.Echo = new Echo({
 broadcaster: 'socket.io',
 host: window.location.hostname,
 auth: { 
    headers: { 
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    } 
  }
});
```